# Fact formation with ceiling in prolog

Tags: prolog

Can I define a fact of the following form,

```
test(X, ceiling(sqrt(X))).
```

Where, `X` is related to `ceiling(sqrt(X))`.

I think  , I could have done the following to receive the desired output,

```
test(X, Y) :- Y is ceiling(sqrt(X)).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define:`test(X, ceiling(sqrt(X))).` 
This means that you have as fact atoms in the above form so if you query:

```
?- test(X, ceiling(sqrt(X))).
true.
```

because you defined this clause.
But note that if you query:

```
?- test(1.5, 2).
false.
```

It returns false because 2 is ceiling(sqrt(1.5)) but the predicate is waiting a syntax like ceiling(sqrt(1.5)) and not the result 2.

Another example:

```
?- test(1.5, Y).
Y = ceiling(sqrt(1.5)).
```

and

```
?- test(X,ceiling(sqrt(1.5))).
X = 1.5.
```

Also notice that :

```
test(X) :- X is ceiling(sqrt(X)).
```

is always failing for any input X (because there is no such X that equals to  ceiling(sqrt(X)). )and querying test(X) will have instantiation problems due to is/2.

Maybe what you meant to write is:

```
test(X,X1) :-  X1 is ceiling(sqrt(X)).
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I don't understand your clause

```
test(X) :- X is ceiling(sqrt(X)).
```

You're imposing the equation (not assignment: equation) " X = ceiling(sqrt(X)) ".

I think you're intention was

```
test(X, Y) :- Y is ceiling(sqrt(X)).
```

Is this what do you want?